# The easiest way to beat Deep Freeze?

Tags: windows, security, deep-freeze

I am going to program some application that adds an exe file to Startup of user's windows.

I can easily do that, unless if Deep Freeze be installed on the windows, which doesn't allow me to do that.

Okay, I know that I might be able to beat Deep Freeze using a boot disk or something like that, but I want to do that by a program, which runs on windows.

I can't delete Deep Freeze or its DLLs, or change registry keys, because they are likely frozen, and they'll be back after restart.

Anyway?

Comment: The answer is no there isn't any way other than a boot you control.

Comment: @MostafaFarzán - How about disable `Deep Freeze` install your application the enable it again.  As for the downvote, this is a localized problem, if you have permission to install the program then you have the ability to disable `Deep Freeze`.

Comment: Okay, so I need someways to boot the computer and then I disable it. Thanks, here we go.

Comment: If the user installs a program to prevent other programs from adding auto-start entries, then circumventing that program is against the user intend. So it sounds like you want to write malware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an external medium to boot as that is the only way. You cannot do this programmatically. As per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Freeze_%28software%29) :

*Deep Freeze cannot protect the operating system and hard drive upon which it is installed if the computer is booted from another medium (such as an external hard drive, a USB device, optical media, or network server).*